# Discord thread webhook

Tags: discord, bots

I got the webhook from Server > Settings > Integrations. But with the provided documentation by Discord I only can reply in channel.

```
import requests
url = 'webhook_url'

data = {
    "content": "Test"
}
result = requests.post(url, json=data)
print(result.json())
```

Is there any way to to reply in Thread directly? using some Thread ID or smth.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have just to add `thread_id` as the query param in the webhook url. instead of in the post body.

Answer (score 0):

https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook#execute-webhook

According to the Discord webhook developer docs, just append ?thread_id to the query params

Comment: How do you get the `thread_id` though?

Comment: @wilmol thread IDs are the thread "channel" IDs, you can grab them in the Discord client by having developer mode on and right-clicking on a thread then "Copy ID"

https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/threads

Comment: Ah I see. I was hoping to start a thread using webhooks.